# One implication (on Measure)

Tags: measure-theory, boolean-algebra

Please be noted that charges are finitely additive measures and measure are countably additive ones.

[image]

> **Theorem 2.1.** *Let $\mu$ be a charge on a Boolean algebra $B$. Each of the following conditions implies the succeeding condition.* 
>  $\quad(\rm i)$ *$\mu$ is strongly nonatomic on $B$.* 
>  $\;\;\,(\rm ii)$ *$\mu$ is strongly continuous on $B$.* 
>  $\;\,(\rm iii)$ *$\mu$ is nonatomic on $B$.*
>
> *If $\mu$ is a measure and $B$ is a Boolean $\sigma$-algebra then the conditions are equivalent.*

for charges $ (i)\Rightarrow (ii) \Rightarrow  (iii)$, and they are equivalent for measures. The author said, the implications $ (i)\Rightarrow (ii) \Rightarrow  (iii)$ follow from their definitions.

> **But I am stack in proving $(ii) \Rightarrow  (iii)$ ??!! I do not know how to conclude it.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mu(b) > 0$, and let $b_1,\,\dotsc,\,b_n$ as in definition, where $\varepsilon = \mu(b)/2$.

Consider

$$(b\wedge b_i),\quad 1\leqslant i \leqslant n.$$

Comment: I am sorry I could not grasp it from your hint.

Comment: You have $b = (b\wedge b_1) \vee (b\wedge b_2) \vee \dotsc \vee (b\wedge b_n)$. Does that show you how to proceed?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong: Take $\varepsilon$ and $b\ni B$ with $\mu(b)>0$, since for each $i$, $\mu(b_i)<\varepsilon$ and $b_i\cap b\subseteq b$, then $0<\mu(b_i\cap b)<\mu(b)$. I get it but I do not know how type it mathematically.

Comment: You have to choose $\varepsilon < \mu(b)$. With what I wrote in the answer and previous comment, $$\mu(b) = \sum_{i=1}^n \mu(b\wedge b_i).$$ So there must be an index $1 \leqslant i_0 \leqslant n$ with $\mu(b\wedge b_{i_0}) > 0$. But also $b\wedge b_{i_0} \leqslant b_{i_0}$, so $\mu(b\wedge b_{i_0}) \leqslant \mu(b_{i_0}) \leqslant \varepsilon < \mu(b)$. Use $b\wedge b_{i_0}$ for $c$.

Comment: Thanks for your time and comments.